# Apple PhotoKit API - access to faces/people

Tags: ios, photokit

Currently does the PhotoKit API allow access to the People album & the face information or is all that private?

For example is it possible to fetch all of the photos of "John Smith" if I have him tagged in my library and then access the facial recognition information associated with each photo?

Comment: Smart album types are here; https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollectionsubtype